Blender animation exported as .fbx won't even preview in Unity
I recently exported an animation from Blender as a .fbx file, and although I can access the animation object from Unity, there's no way to make it run on Unity, not even in preview. This is my animation tab,

As you can see, the "bake animations" button is disabled Idk for what reason, altough it is checked in Blender settings while I export the animation from Blender.
Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated thanks!
I looked up the issue all around goolge but with no luck so far, even tried using chat GPT.

Blender only exports animations to FBX files if you somehow associate the animation with the a specific armature. One way to do this is to add every animation as a separate clip within the NLA Editor as an Action Strip
Within Blender, open the animation timeline and change the tab to the "Action Editor". Then, for every animation you wish to include, click "Push Down" to add it to the armature as an NLA Action.

Turns out if I export the .fbx unchecking both NLA Strips and All Action in the Bake Animation tab, the animation actually previews in Unity. But still there seem to be no way to make it run at runtime as the object ( a life bar in this case ) spawns. I would like to add that the animation uses a scale ttransformation, I don't know if this is relevant, and although it is make in blender it only uses 2D primitives such as planes. About what you said, if I try to click push down it says "Actions must have at least on keyframe" but I can't add keyframes

did you added an animator, you need to add the animation to a rig of a model,
and if you want to use the animation you have to add the Animator component to you model gameObject.
or if you just want a preview go to your assets where your animation is saved make one left klick on the animation an look right down corner ther must be an player

Yes I added the animator, and also that's what I was talking about, whenever it should be previewed in unity it simply doesn't.
